# avoid repeating same code for each item with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have the following inline javascript, im using a jquery countdown plugin to display time remaining.

this code exists with each "Comment" on the page, hence it is repeating multiple time on the page. How can I make this external? and avoid the repetition?

im using .nt mvc razor and attaching id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    var dateLeft = new Date(@(item.UnixTicks));
    $('#countdown-@(item.ID)').countdown({until: dateLeft, format:'MS', onExpiry: liftOff, onTick: watchCountdown}); 

    function liftOff() { 
        alert('We have lift off!'); 
    } 

    function watchCountdown(periods) { 
        $('#monitor-@(item.ID)').text('Just ' + periods[5] + ' minutes and ' + 
            periods[6] + ' seconds to go'); 
    }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `UnixTicks` into an attribute in the comment, give all of the comments a `class="comment"`, and loop over them:

```
$('.Comment').each(function() { 
    var dateLeft = new Date(parseInt($(this).attr('data-unixticks'), 10));
    ...
});
```

Comment: And same with the `item.ID` attribute.. :)

Comment: If the `#monitor-` elements are nested inside the "main" `div` then it would be even better to give them class e.g. *monitor* then simple `$(this).find(".monitor")` will find it. Nice!